# ¿Como realizar ciclos de for regulares y el usuario ingrese valores a la matriz y indice donde se ubica el valor?

Tags: java, bucle-for, matriz

```
    int [][] valores = new int[3][3];
        
    System.out.print ("Ingrese un valor en la posici�n [0][0]: ");
     valores[0][0] = lector.nextInt();
     
     System.out.print ("Ingrese un valor en la posici�n [0][1]: ");
     valores[0][1] = lector.nextInt();
     
     System.out.print ("Ingrese un valor en la posici�n [0][2]: ");
    valores[0][2] = lector.nextInt();
     
     System.out.print ("Ingrese un valor en la posici�n [1][0]: ");
     valores[1][0] = lector.nextInt();
     
     System.out.print ("Ingrese un valor en la posici�n [1][1]: ");
     valores[1][1] = lector.nextInt();
     
     System.out.print ("Ingrese un valor en la posici�n [1][2]: ");
    valores[1][2] = lector.nextInt();
     
     System.out.print ("Ingrese un valor en la posici�n [2][0]: ");
     valores[2][0] = lector.nextInt();
     
     System.out.print ("Ingrese un valor en la posici�n [2][1]: ");
     valores[2][1] = lector.nextInt();
     
     System.out.print ("Ingrese un valor en la posici�n [2][2]: ");
    valores[2][2] = lector.nextInt();
            
    System.out.println ("----------------------------------------------------");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < valores[0].length; j++){
            System.out.print (valores[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println ("");
```

**Necesito realizar un programa que tenga una matriz de valores enteros de 3x3.
Mediante el uso de ciclo for regulares necesito solicitarle al usuario que ingrese valores a la matriz indicando el indice en el cual va a insertar el valor.
Una vez cargados los datos, se utiliza ciclos for-each para imprimir la matriz.
Ejemplo.**

````
[3][4][5]
[6][7][8]
[9][9][9] ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pedir los valores.

```
for (int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < valores[i].length; j++) {

        System.out.print("Ingrese un valor en la posición [" + i + "][" + j + "]: ");
        valores[i][j] = lector.nextInt();
    }


}
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias.